# Clickear en un elemento con nombre de clases repetidas Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, click

muy buenas, estoy empezando en esto.

Tengo la siguiente duda, tengo este div:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="Slotbazar aa0 elemento 1 masBazar"></div>
<div class="Slotbazar aa1 elemento 2 masBazar"></div>
<div class="Slotbazar aa2 elemento 3 masBazar"></div>
<div class="Slotbazar aa3 elemento 4 masBazar"></div>
<div class="Slotbazar aa4 elemento 5 masBazar"></div>
</div>
```

Por lo que se, si la clase tiene un salto de línea, solo leerá la primera línea, según esto estoy leyendo la parte **Slotbazar** y no (**aa4 elemento 4**), la cual diferencia a los elementos, como son 5, no da click al elemento que requiero.

Probé con:

```
Bazar = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ‘//*XPATH del elemento requerido’).click() # El elemento no es clickeable

Bazar = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, ‘Slotbazar aa3 elemento 4 masBazar’).click()

Bazar = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, ‘Slotbazar’+’ elemento 4’).click()# No such element: Unable to locate element
```

No logro hacerle click a este elemento, si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradecería, estoy usando Python.

Saludos.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor haz el [tour] y consulta [ask]. La etiqueta de tu primer div **carece del caracter de cierre >** ¿fue un error de transcripción? o, quizás sea un error que afecta el funcionamiento de tu código.

Answer (score 1):

La manera sencilla de reconocer elementos donde el nombre de su clase contiene espacios es utilizar `CSS_SELECTOR` y reemplazar el espacio `" "` por un punto `.`

Un ejemplo:

```
bazar = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.Slotbazar.aa3.elemento.4.masBazar')
bazar.click()
```

Otra opción es aprovecharse de la función `replace`, ya que utilizamos una cadena de caracteres como selector, para reemplazar `" "` por `.`:

```
bazar = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.Slotbazar aa3 elemento 4 masBazar'.replace(' ','.'))
bazar.click()
```

Comment: Concuerdo con que la mejor manera es CSS. De hecho cuando se usan espacios cada palabra es una clase, deberia bastar con find_element_by_css_selector('.aa3') para seleccionar el cuarto elemento.